# How do I access clipboard from google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

How do I get the search string from the clipboard to replace the value "dog" here? Is the clipboard accessible in google-sheet scripts?

```
function onSearch(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var search_string = "dog"
var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search_string)
var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow()
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.alert("search row: " + search_row)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot access the clipboard programmatically in JS due to security reasons. Please check this tips from [Google documentation](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/drive/advanced-copy-and-paste-with-web-clipboard/) for copy and paste functionality with web clipboard.

Comment: I cannot view the link